# Custom environments for Gym Error: Cannot re-register id

Tags: python-3.x, openai-gym

I want to create my own Gym environment. I have followed the steps explained in here: https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/docs/creating-environments.md. Based on their suggestion, I created the environment (link:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RmcSBZYKCARaNsdlOsACrk9ls8snqxlj ). After installing and running the environment is created and displays the print out "Created, Step". But, when I had again pressed the 'Run' button (spyder ide:python3.7) it showed me the "Error: Cannot re-register id: foo-v0". The problem would disapper temporarily, if I press 'Restart kernel' button. But again 'Run' would show the same error. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
runfile('F:/gym-foo/a.py', wdir='F:/gym-foo')
Created
Step

runfile('F:/gym-foo/a.py', wdir='F:/gym-foo')
Reloaded modules: gym_foo, gym_foo.envs, gym_foo.envs.foo_env
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "F:\gym-foo\a.py", line 3, in <module>
    env = gym.make('gym_foo:foo-v0')

  File "C:\Users\nasif\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 142, in make
    return registry.make(id, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\nasif\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 86, in make
    spec = self.spec(path)

  File "C:\Users\nasif\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 106, in spec
    importlib.import_module(mod_name)

  File "C:\Users\nasif\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "F:\gym-foo\gym_foo\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    entry_point='gym_foo.envs:FooEnv',

  File "C:\Users\nasif\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 139, in register
    return registry.register(id, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\nasif\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 132, in register
    raise error.Error('Cannot re-register id: {}'.format(id))

Error: Cannot re-register id: foo-v0
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue today. Here is how I resolved it:

```
import gym
env_dict = gym.envs.registration.registry.env_specs.copy()
for env in env_dict:
    if 'foo' in env:
        print("Remove {} from registry".format(env))
        del gym.envs.registration.registry.env_specs[env]
import foo_env
```

This gets rid of the original `foo_env` from your current python session, either on Jupyter labs or in terminal.

Comment: I shall check it

Comment: @user1850484 Any updates bud? Would love to help further!

Answer (score 0):

```
import gym

env_dict = gym.envs.registration.registry.env_specs.copy()


for env in env_dict:
    if 'CustomEnv-v0' in env:
        print("Remove {} from registry".format(env))
        del gym.envs.registration.registry.env_specs[env]

import envs


env = gym.make('CustomEnv-v0')
env.step()
env.reset()
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because of multiprocessing. Try putting the code that calls `register` inside an `if __name__ == '__main__':` clause. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be caused by naming a Python file the same name as a module or package containing the environment.  In my case, I was attempting to use a gym environment from the simglucose package, but had named my Python file simglucose.py.  This (quite misleading) error was the result.  Renaming the Python file fixed the problem.  For more details, see my question and answer here: [Error Only When Code is in a Certain Directory: gym.error.Error: Cannot re-register id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73411966/error-only-when-code-is-in-a-certain-directory-gym-error-error-cannot-re-regis)

Update: I also found a case where both the deregistration step (credit to the answer above, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61648353/3187892) and this fix were both required, so do try both if neither is working by itself.