# Error Only When Code is in a Certain Directory: gym.error.Error: Cannot re-register id

Tags: conda, openai-gym

I am trying to use the simglucose package with OpenAI gym.  I am encountering a strange problem; when I run the code below in a certain directory (let's call it `problem_dir/`), it fails with the error below.  However, when I copy-paste the file to other locations, it runs fine (I tried about 10 other locations, including child and parent directories of `problem_dir/`).  What could cause an error like the one below, but ***only*** when the Python file is in `problem_dir/`?

Problematic code:

```
import gym
from gym.envs.registration import register
register(
    id='simglucose-adolescent2-v0',
    entry_point='simglucose.envs:T1DSimEnv',
    kwargs={'patient_name': 'adolescent#002'}
)
env = gym.make('simglucose-adolescent2-v0') # ERROR HERE
```

The error:

```
(seldonian_library_env) james@james-desktop2019-Ub18:~$ python seldonian_library_repos/Engine/seldonian/RL/environments/temp.py 
/home/james/anaconda3/envs/seldonian_library_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py:17: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: Parameters to load are deprecated.  Call .resolve and .require separately.
  result = entry_point.load(False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seldonian_library_repos/Engine/seldonian/RL/environments/temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    env = gym.make('simglucose-adolescent2-v0')
  File "/home/james/anaconda3/envs/seldonian_library_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 164, in make
    return registry.make(id)
  File "/home/james/anaconda3/envs/seldonian_library_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 122, in make
    env = spec.make()
  File "/home/james/anaconda3/envs/seldonian_library_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 88, in make
    cls = load(self._entry_point)
  File "/home/james/anaconda3/envs/seldonian_library_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 17, in load
    result = entry_point.load(False)
  File "/home/james/anaconda3/envs/seldonian_library_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2450, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/james/anaconda3/envs/seldonian_library_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2456, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/home/james/seldonian_library_repos/Engine/seldonian/RL/environments/simglucose.py", line 62, in <module>
    register(
  File "/home/james/anaconda3/envs/seldonian_library_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 161, in register
    return registry.register(id, **kwargs)
  File "/home/james/anaconda3/envs/seldonian_library_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 154, in register
    raise error.Error('Cannot re-register id: {}'.format(id))
gym.error.Error: Cannot re-register id: simglucose-adolescent2-v0
```

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.6 and Python 3.8.13.

**Update:**

The problem has "spread"; it's occurring in other directories now too, but not all directories.  Also, when I change my code to try to deregister the environment before registering, as follows, I get the following new error:

Modified code:

```
import gym
env_dict = gym.envs.registration.registry.env_specs.copy()

for env in env_dict:
    if 'simglucose' in env:
        print(f"Removing {env}")
        del gym.envs.registration.registry.env_specs[env]

from gym.envs.registration import register
register(
    id='simglucose-adolescent2-v0',
    entry_point='simglucose.envs:T1DSimEnv',
    kwargs={'patient_name': 'adolescent#002'}
)

env = gym.make('simglucose-adolescent2-v0')
```

New error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simglucose.envs'; 'simglucose' is not a package
```

Strangely, when I run this modified code in the directories where the 1st error above is not occurring (still using the same pip/conda environment), this new error does not occur either.  I have checked for hidden files and found nothing other the the __pychache__ directory.  I tried deleting that, but it changes nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import simglucose
```

worked fine, but

```
import simglucose.envs #gym was calling pkg_resources which was calling this statement
```

failed (depending on the directory) **because my Python file was named simglucose.py.  Renaming the file fixed the problem.**

Somehow, this was also causing not only the error in the update above, but the original `Cannot re-register id` error.  The error no longer occurred after renaming the Python file (no need to deregister the environment as I did in the update).

**TLDR: If you are getting an error like this, make sure your Python file names do not conflict with any module/package names.**

Update: I also found a case where both the deregistration step (credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61648353/3187892) and this fix were both required, so do try both if neither is working by itself.